# SWIG2 template return type namespace not detected

Tags: java, templates, namespaces, return-value, swig

I'm swigging to Java. I'm trying to get a templated member func to use some templated return type, which i have to give a name of course (since otherwise SWIG would not create the needed source).

test.i is like:

```
%module Test
%{

#include <vector>

namespace ns
{
  class C
  {
  public:
    template <class T>
    void doit(const std::vector<T>& v) {}; // will need std:vector<int> version of that
  };
}

%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%template(Ivec) std::vector<int>; // here I'm defining an std::vector<int> to use ...

%nspace ns::C;
namespace ns
{
  class C
  {
  public:
    template <class T>
    void doit(const std::vector<T>& v);
  };
}
%extend ns::C
{
  %template(Idoit) doit<int>; // ... here
}
```

When calling:

```
swig -c++ -java -outdir mypack -package mypack test.i
```

mypack/ns/C.java looks like:

```
package mypack.ns;

public class C {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public C(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  public static long getCPtr(C obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
  delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        mypack.TestJNI.delete_ns_C(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public void Idoit(Ivec v) { // OK, Ivec is beeing used ... but not with its fqn
    mypack.TestJNI.ns_C_Idoit(swigCPtr, this, Ivec.getCPtr(v), v);
  }

  public C() {
    this(mypack.TestJNI.new_ns_C(), true);
  }

}
```

which is fine but Ivec is defined in mypack/Ivec.java, that is in the 'global' package and thus compiling the source fails. How can I get SWIG to use Ivec's full qualified name!?

I have also tried to push Ivec into the same namespace as C like:

```
%module Test
%{

#include <vector>

namespace ns
{
  class C
  {
  public:
    template <class T>
    void doit(const std::vector<T>& v) {}; // will need std:vector<int> version of that
  };
}

%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%nspace ns::C;
%nspace ns::Ivec;
namespace ns
{
  %template("ns.Ivec") std::vector<int>;
  class C
  {
  public:
    template <class T>
    void doit(const std::vector<T>& v);
  };
}
%extend ns::C
{
  %template(Idoit) doit<int>;
}
```

but that has the effect that Ivec is still located in mypack and mypack/ns/C.java is now:

```
package mypack.ns;

public class C {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public C(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  public static long getCPtr(C obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        mypack.TestJNI.delete_ns_C(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public void Idoit(SWIGTYPE_p_ns__std__vectorT_int_t v) { // aaaaaaaaah
    mypack.TestJNI.ns_C_Idoit(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_ns__std__vectorT_int_t.getCPtr(v));
  }

  public C() {
    this(mypack.TestJNI.new_ns_C(), true);
  }

}
```

and now SWIG doesn't even recognize the cool Ivec :(

Has anybody experienced similar difficulties and give me some hint?

B I G T H X
bbb

Answer (score 0):

By now I fixed the first version this by adding

```
%typemap(javaimports) ns::C "
import mypack.Ivec;
"
```

right ...

```
[ ... ]
%nspace ns::C;
// ... here
namespace ns
{
[ ... ]
```

Now the name will be resolved by the java compiler.

Cheers.